# What was at the top of the pyramid?

Tags: westworld-2016

On several occasions we're told about the "pyramid", supposedly the steps that need to be achieved in order to achieve consciousness.

**So what goes at the top of the pyramid?**

[image]

> When Dolores reaches the city in the sand, there is a conversation between her and Arnold. Arnold tells her that she is alive and it's based on his theory, that consciousness has the stages, memory, improvisation and something else, that was on top of the pyramid. ***As far as I understand from Dolores encounter with her true self, he was taking about intuition (hearing your own inner voice), but still I'm unsure if I understand autors' idea right.***

Comment: Could you ask this in a way that isn't a spoiler? There are multiple references to both kinds of "pyramid" ([1](http://cdn.fansided.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/343/files/2016/10/Westworld-theory.jpg), [2](https://nyoobserver.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/screen-shot-2016-12-05-at-11-42-19-am.png?w=635)) in earlier episodes.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/westworld/comments/57v16i/what_is_the_missing_piece_at_the_top_of_the/

Comment: I've tried to make this less spoiler-tastic. Asking a question where 100% of the useful text is behind a spoiler tag suggests a lack of imagination :-)

Comment: @Valorum thanks, in fact I did not remember references to the pyramid from the other episodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The peak of the pyramid is *consciousness*

> **Ford:** *He [Arnold] wanted to create consciousness. He imagined it as a pyramid.*

but either Arnold nor Ford were able to work out what they could do to get the hosts from the bottom of the pyramid (mere automatons) to the top (fully actualised, conscious beings). They intuited a few of the stages that *seemed* fairly obvious such as "*Memory, improvisation [and] self-interest*" but then got stuck when trying to work out the final step needed.

Arnold decided that the easiest way to break the impasse was to cheat. Instead of creating *true* consciousness, he "bootstrapped" a second internal voice that the hosts could choose to listen to or ignore as they saw fit. As to what *actually* goes in the top of the pyramid, the answer is that we (and they) simply don't know.

> **Ford:** *And at the top? Never got there.*

But it's telling that all of the hosts that achieve some measure of self-actualisation are those that have

- Been ***active for long periods***
- Have ***suffered*** enormously
- Have been ***totally reprogrammed*** (re-tasked) at least once.

Any one of those (or a combination of all three plus other factors) could be the missing link that Arnold, and latterly Ford were looking for.

Comment: Ford explains that the suffering is necessary to create the realisation that there is a difference between the world as it is and how you want it, and that's a key to achieving consciousness.